# Accessing data frame columns from within a loop in R

Tags: r, calculated-columns, abstraction

I have data on repeated referrals, with each subsequent referral (per case) in it's own column. The number of these columns can change for every analysis that is run, so I need the script to account for this.

I then need to create a new column that calculates the difference in dates between the first and second / second and third (and so on) columns, returning it as an integer.

I've got almost all of the way there, but then when I'm trying to abstract the data.frame selection I'm getting no where.

```
for(i in 1:max.reref){
  old <- paste(sprintf("reref_%03d",i))
  new <- sprintf("reref_%03d",i+1)
  colname <- paste("DateDif", i,i+1,sep="")

  dataset[,colname] <- as.integer(as.Date(dataset[,c(old)]) - as.Date(dataset[,c(new)]))

}
```

I've tried the final line in the following ways with no success:

```
dataset[,colname] <- as.integer(as.Date(dataset[,old]) - as.Date(dataset[,new]))

dataset[,colname] <- as.integer(as.Date(dataset[,paste(old)]) - as.Date(dataset[,paste(new)]))

dataset[,colname] <- as.integer(as.Date(dataset$old) - as.Date(dataset$new))
```

With no success.

The problem seems to be that when the variable (storing the column name) is input into the column selector (either [] or $), it is being output as the column name, not the column itself.

There is obviously a way to do this, but it's none of the obvious ones.

**EDIT: **
It was requested that I add the head of my data, unfortunately it's 246 variable's wide and it's sensitive data, so instead I'll give a sample of the variables that are relating to this question.

```
      id_a   RefDate1   RefDate2   RefDate3
1 3229.396 2007-09-20 2015-07-12 2000-06-18
2 4579.532 2004-12-06 2000-06-22 2002-02-07
3  917.971 2007-12-05 2012-02-16 2016-04-29
4 4537.704 2007-03-30 2006-09-27 2006-03-28
5 6599.104 2010-06-06 2017-03-31 2015-08-23
```

Another question was what does `max.reref` refer to, this is the number of referrals for this dataset (e.g. date columns that need to be affected by the function/loop).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please add `head(dataset)` as well

Comment: Also please provide `max.reref`.

Comment: Are you working with data.tables from the `data.table` package? Your assessment would be true with this package. In that case, you'd add `with=FALSE` argument to each `dataset[...]` call.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` and `dplyr`

```
dataset.dt <- melt(dataset, id.vars = "id_a")
data.diff  <- dataset.dt %>% 
              arrange(id_a, variable) %>%
              mutate(diff = difftime(value, lag(value), unit = "days")) %>%
              mutate(diff = ifelse(variable == "RefDate1", NA, diff))
dataset.new<- dcast(data.diff, id_a ~ variable, value.var = "diff")
```

This yields

```
      id_a RefDate1  RefDate2   RefDate3
   917.971       NA  1534.000  1533.9583
  3229.396       NA  2852.000 -5502.0000
  4537.704       NA  -184.000  -182.9583
  4579.532       NA -1628.042   595.0417
  6599.104       NA  2490.000  -586.0000
```

The reason `RefDate1 = NA`, is because I used the `lag(value)`, which is to say I took `RefDate1 - RefDate2` and stored the difference at `RefDate2`. Then the result was `dcast`ed to create the above. Now we can merge this to the original dataset as follows

```
dataset.all <- merge(dataset, dataset.new, by = "id_a, suffixes = c(".date", ".diff"))
```

Some modifications to this code that you can make are using `lead` instead of `lag` (check it out!), in which case you need to change the second `mutate` to `RefDate___`.

Comment: Typically this section of the code came just after being `dcast`, so I've gone back and worked it into an earlier section. 
Thank you though, this has worked a treat.

Comment: If this is the solution you are looking for, you mind upvoting? thanks